# Can't install Laravel homestead using Vagrant on Windows 10

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have just downloaded the latest version of Vagrant 2.2.15 and VMware. I tried to run

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

But I get

```
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
```

`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

```
URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error: schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

After checking https://app.vagrantup.com/laravel/boxes/homestead I run

```
vagrant init laravel/homestead
```

Then try to run

```
vagrant up
```

But I never got it to work and keep getting the same error message. I found this solution https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/6764 and installed `MS Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributables`  but can't run `vagrant up` or don't even know how to install homestead after the last update. I used to install it the old same way without issues multiple times but today I couldn't

I tried

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
```

But I get

```
There was an error while downloading the metadata for this box.
The error message is shown below:

schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

I checked the temp here `.vagrant.d\tmp` but it's empty.
Any help please on installing and running laravel homestead on Windows 10?

Comment: i have the same problem, installing vc2010 doesnt work, but then i **paused my antivirus protection**, **IT WORKS**

Answer (score 24):

Disabling antivirus software (Kaspersky in my case) solved the problem for me.

Comment: strange, but this was my problem too and it worked for me too (disbling Kaspersky for 5 min till the command 'vagrant up' was initiated)

Comment: This was an issue for me too using Kasperspy. Disabled it, worked fine.

Comment: This was the problem for me too

Answer (score 8):

For me It was Kaspersky as well, but you don't have to disable it everytime you can add an exception to Kaspersky network trusted addresses

Open Kaspersky

1. Click on the bottom left cog.
2. Open Network Settings
3. Click on Trusted addresses
4. add: `vagrantcloud.com`
5. save
6. Test
   `vagrant up`
   `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`

I assume if you having this issue and it's using another Antivirus the problem /solution is the same, or maybe some proxy intercepting https traffic.

---

[image: kaspersky dashboard]
[image: network settings]
[image: trusted addresses]

Comment: It takes more then just vagrant cloud, also:
vagrantcloud-files-production.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com,

app.vagrantup.com,

archivist.vagrantup.com,

vagrantcloud.com,

Comment: Same worked for Avast for me.

Answer (score 5):

We also only recently encountered this error when using the 2.2.15 version of Vagrant. Downgrading back to Vagrant 2.2.14 was our answer. This could be a Vagrant bug.

Comment: I got this same error when using a fresh install of Vagrant 2.2.18.  Turning off my virus protection (Symantec) and retrying Vagrant Up resulted in same error.  Following your 'hint', I backed the install of Vagrant down from patch #18 through to #14 (I tried all installations from .18 to .14).  It was at 14 that vagrant properly booted a VB hosted Debian 11 and 10 VMs.  Thanks for hint.

Comment: I was facing the same problem. Just downgraded to Vagrant 2.2.14 and it works! Before that I tried with different versions but version 2.2.14 did the job for me. Thanks for saving the day.

Answer (score 4):

Temporarily disable web shield if you're using avast.

Tried adding the domains and app to a trusted list but still without success. This seemed to be the minimum to get the job done

[image]

Comment: Or Menu > Settings > Protection > Core Shields > Web Shield > Enable HTTPS scanning: Off – 
https://support.avast.com/en-us/article/use-antivirus-https-scan/#pc