# How to fix unable to check revocation for the certificate when downloading a remote file in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

As part of my `Vagrantfile` I have

```rb
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "https://get.docker.com", name: "dockers"
```

I'm behind a corporate proxy. I appended my corporate certificate to
`C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\cacert.pem`. Also, I set this environments variable `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` & `SSL_CERT_FILE` both to `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\cacert.pem` which has the certificate.

But still `vagrant up` fails with the following message:

```
schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
 INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Vagrant::Errors::DownloaderError", "An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error\nmessage, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try\nagain.\n\nschannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.\r"]
```

My guess is that Ruby (being used by Vagrant) cannot find the cert or the call to get the revocation list is blocked. Any ideas what is the exact issue here and how to fix it?

**Update**

In the debug mode it appears that curl (possibly called from Ruby?) is trying to download the file

```
INFO downloader: Downloader starting download:
 INFO downloader:   -- Source: https://get.docker.com
 INFO downloader:   -- Destination: C:/Users/John/.vagrant.d/tmp/12288a08-a7ba-3d92-96ff-8bf28e739099-remote-script
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\HashiCorp\\Vagrant\\embedded\\bin/curl.EXE", "-q", "--fail", "--location", "--max-redirs", "10", "--verbose", "--user-agent", 
 "Vagrant/2.2.16 (+https://www.vagrantup.com; ruby2.6.7) ", "--output", "C:/Users/John/.vagrant.d/tmp/12288a08-a7ba-3d92-96ff-8bf28e739099-remote-script", "https://get.docker.com"]
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stderr:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 99.84.174.91:443...
* Connected to get.docker.com (99.84.174.91) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: ALPN, offering http/1.1
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with get.docker.com port 443
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67089293) .

As mentioned there, disabling the antivirus software till `vagrant init` was initialized solved the problem.

Comment: Disabling anti virus is not an option for me

Answer (score 0):

i am using win10 without any third-party antivirus. I just mannuly used the virtual machine file in dir `.vagrant.d\boxes\`,  opening vmware and scanning the dir .